# Normalize data with R

Tags: r, som

I have a dataframe called `data` which contains 5 columns and approximately 181 rows.

I'm trying to run some algorithm on this dataframe, but I have to do some pre-processing beforehand and normalize the columns to have zero and 1.
I am using R and the problem that i have columns whit not numeric data like this:

```
Name       ZwaveType ProprietesName Value                Date
Switcher19         0              2     1 2014-03-01 06:45:00
Switcher5          0              2     1 2014-03-01 07:00:00
Switcher15         0              2     1 2014-03-01 07:15:00
Switcher4          0              2     1 2014-03-01 07:14:30
Switcher15         0              2     0 2014-03-01 07:25:00
Switcher19         0              2     0 2014-03-01 07:45:00
```

I'd like to ask how can I achieve normalization with R for this case?

Comment: By normalize, what do you mean? How do you want to normalize your data?

Comment: Why would you normalise text and data fields, `ProprietesName`, `Name`?

Comment: I want to generate new column to normalize data according to Column Value and Dtae to separate data whitch have Value 1 and those having Value 0

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
col.classes <- sapply(mydata,class)
num.cols <- (col.classes=="numeric")
mydata[,num.cols] <- scale(mydata[,num.cols])
```

Comment: how can I use this function sapply? and what do you mean by 'class' is it the package class?

Comment: This is intended to be a complete, literal answer: it assumes `mydata` is your data set. `class` is a function in base R -- see `?class`.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: My question was about how to use this function and my data is not numeric , Ihave used already the function normalize :    normalize(dataset, byrow=TRUE) and Ihave this error Erreur dans colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' doit être numérique

Comment: I thought of an idea in order to normalize the data from my dataframe. In fact I can overlook the Name column and replace it with a column ID (this is already numeric) so the only non-numeric column that I still have is Date, so I think about browsing my dataframe and I'll generate a new column for each date. as I associate a value, and for the similar dates I will associate the same value, but I don't know until now if it's possible to do this business with R ??